# Delphi: TWebBrowser with SSL certificate file?

Tags: delphi, ssl

I am accessing a web site using TWebBrowser component in Delphi 7. The call is quite simple:

WebBrowser.Navigate(URL);

This site needs specific certificate that I have as a file, lets call it test.cer. Without it, the site will not open. As far as I remember, I have added the certificate to the Windows certificate repository on my PC. That's why when I call "WebBrowser.Navigate", a dialog pops up asking me to confirm certificate:

[image]

I want to skip this dialog and provide the certificate directly. I tried my program on other computers without a certificate installed and, as I expected, the URL did not load at all. That's why it is important to provide test.cer somehow. Is it possible to do it with TWebBrowser component or I should look for other alternatives like IdHttp+IdSSLOpenSSL?

Comment: The site is clearly visible, you might want to redact that, too.

Comment: You might try to implement `IInternetSecurityManager` and in the `ProcessUrlAction` wait for the `URLACTION_CLIENT_CERT_PROMPT` action and disallow the dialog to show.